# Finding the remainder of $123^{456}+78^9$ divided by $7$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic

> Find the remainder when $123^{456}+78^9$ is divided by $7$.

This would be $123^{456}+78^9\pmod7,$ but is there any way to find some slick congruence? I don't really understand how to find congruences.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/81228/how-do-i-compute-ab-bmod-c-by-hand

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$123^{456}\equiv1\bmod 7$ by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem) that $a^{p-1}\equiv1\bmod p$ if $a\not\equiv0\bmod p$.

$78^9\equiv1^9=1\bmod 7$, because $78=11\times7+1$.

Comment: Woah, I've never knew about this theorem before. Thank you so much!!!